# Change Firebase functions region on client side flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

I changed the region of my firebase functions. Now I can't call the endpoints anymore from client side. I guess I've to change the region on the client side too, but how?
I tried this, but its not working:

```
FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(app: Firebase.app(), region: "europe-west3")
        .httpsCallable(...)...
```

I'm getting the error: `[firebase_functions/not-found] NOT FOUND`

Answer (score -1):

Per [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#default-cloud-location) all resources must share the same location. Once location is set in a project, it cannot be changed. You must create a new project.

> **Warning:** Setting the location for one of these services (that is, Cloud Firestore, Cloud Storage, or scheduled functions) also sets the location for the others. **After you set your project's default GCP resource location, you cannot change it.**

Comment: cloud functions are not concerned

Comment: @quinzo I disagree. "Firebase Functions" = "Cloud Functions for Firebase" according to Firebase Docs.  All Firebase projects are just a collection GCP resources rolled together.

Comment: Cloud Functions for Firebase (scheduled functions only!)

Comment: I am just trying to help. It is very explicit in the docs that `FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('addMessage').call();` in fact calls a Google Cloud Function. You can even log into https://console.cloud.google.com/ and you will see how your Firebase project is running on GCP. You changed the region, and now it suddenly doesn't work. I would at least consider this might be the problem. Again, I'm just trying to help. That's what this whole site is about.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this isn't the issue. It's just about calling the correct endpoint. You can see how it's done  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#client-side_location_selection_for_callable_functions . The only problem is, that this site doesn't provice any information how I can change the region in flutter.